# the output param can be bind by name, not by sort?

Tags: mysql

In the below code，"out b char(8)" can only bind to  the sort of "@bz:=cName,@cz:=cSex",
can i bind it by name(b)?

```
delimiter $$ 
drop procedure if exists test_out1 $$ 

create procedure test_out1(in a CHAR(1), out b char(8),out c char(1) )
begin
   select @bz:=cName,@cz:=cSex from students where cID=a;   
end $$ 
delimiter ;

call test_out1('2',@bx,@cx);
SELECT @bx,@cx
```

-----------------------------------------V2

```
when I use 
create procedure test_out2(in a CHAR(1), out b char(8),out c char(50) )      
begin   
      select cName into b from students where cID=a; 
end $$ 
delimiter ;
```

-->it OK
but whe i use ：

```
create procedure test_out2(in a CHAR(1), out b char(8),out c char(50) )
begin
     select cName into b,cSex to c from students where cID=a;   
end $$
```

-->ERROR， 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

Comment: Dear Ravinder：Thx, but i use [select cName into b, cSex into c from students where cID=a;], it still show [[Err] 1327 - Undeclared variable: cSex] , I'm sure that cSex is a column；so I use[select cName into b,cName into c from students where cID=a;],i also show [[Err] 1327 - Undeclared variable: cName]

Comment: There was a syntax error in my answer. It should be `select cName, cSex into b, c from students where cID=a;`. Corrected it. Please check.

Comment: And , I had another question about inout procedure,Can you help me ,too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340133/how-to-put-and-get-param-by-inout-procedure ....THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `OUT` parameters (`b` and `c`) defined in the procedure definition.
You need not explicitly define the results to other variables, but out parameters.

Change:

```
begin
   select @bz:=cName,@cz:=cSex from students where cID=a;   
end $$
```

to:

```
begin
   select cName, cSex into b, c from students where cID=a;   
end $$
```

And when you execute:

```
call test_out1( '2', @bx, @cx );
SELECT @bx, @cx  ;
```

resulting column values from procedure will be assigned to `@bx` and `@cx` session variables.

***Example***:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT dt date, OUT ts datetime)
BEGIN
   SELECT current_date, now() INTO dt, ts;
END//
delimiter ;
```

Now, call this for a test:

```
CALL simpleproc( @dt, @ts );
select @dt, @ts;
+------------+---------------------+
| @dt        | @ts                 |
+------------+---------------------+
| 2014-03-13 | 2014-03-13 11:19:03 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

***Refer To***:

- [MySQL: CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: Dear：I can use【 select cName into b from students where cID=a;】
but when I use  【select cName into b,cName into c from students where cID=a;】，it show 【You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')]

Comment: by the way， if cSex is emun,how to set in procedure?

Comment: Can you please update your post with the modifications made to your procedure? Better if you add entire part of your trigger code.

Comment: @wayout: If `cSex` is of `enum` type, it only allows predefined values and the syntax is as similar as on any other type of columns.

Comment: Dear  Ravinder ： I have edit my post。 and is there a smple for emum? thx

Comment: I just saw your update. The statement `select cName into b,cSex to c from students where cID=a;` is wrong. You have to use `into` but not `to`. Correct it as `select cName into b, cSex into c from students where cID=a;`

Comment: There was a syntax error in my answer. Corrected it. Please check.