# HOW TO put and get param by inout procedure?

Tags: php

in mysql ：

```
drop PROCEDURE if EXISTS sp_returns_string;
create PROCEDURE  sp_returns_string(inout s_val  varchar(10) CHARACTER set utf8 )
BEGIN
  set s_val=CONCAT(s_val,'-','XXX');
END

set @x='abc';
call sp_returns_string(@x);
select @x 'CT';
```

--->it's OK

in php：

```
$dbh=new PDO($dsn,'root','root',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
$inx='RED';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $inx, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 30);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->closeCursor();
$r = $dbh->query("SELECT $inx AS return_value")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($r) {
     echo sprintf('Customer #%d is %s ', $customerNumber, $r['return_value']);
}
```

it show err message：

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in line 16;
>   line 16 :" $r = $dbh->query("SELECT $inx AS return_value")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); "

How to put get param by inout param?

---------------------------------------------V2
I cahange the code as：

```
    $inx='RED';
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $inx, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 30);
   $stmt->execute();

    echo sprintf( 'Customer  is %s ', $inx );
```

it print as：Customer is RED.

there is not with "-XXX" for output . the correct as ：Customer is RED-XXX

Comment: when i use var_dump($dbh);die(); at line 15；  it show： object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Answer (score 1):

After the `$stmt->execute();`, try the following changes:

```
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->prepare( "SELECT $inx AS return_value" );
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result( $inx );
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->free_result();

echo sprintf( 'Customer #%d is %s ', $customerNumber, $inx );
```

Please refer to the user submitted example on:

- [`PHP.net mysqli Manual: Stored Procedures`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php#112262)

Comment: Dear Ravinder：thx， BUT the result doesn't with output , pleae see my post v2.

Comment: Dear： it show ：[Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::free_result() ]，

Comment: As i know, free_result method only for native MySQL. If you using PDO object, the closest method is close cursor for PDO statements.                         `$stmt->closeCursor();`see this link : http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php